# create once and using interface instance in winforms application lifetime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to figure what is the best pattern of accessing session object in RavenDb database using repository in winform project.

Let say that I have `MainForm.cs`, `NewForm.cs` and `MyRavenRepository.cs`.

Should I inside repository take current `IDocumentStore` instance to assign value to the private variable in the same class which I will than use in actions like

```
private IDocumentStore store;    
public MyRavenRepository(IDocumentStore store)
{
   this.store = store;        
}
public void Create(Car car)
{
    using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
    {
       session.Store(car);
       session.SaveChanges();
    }
 }
```

and every form would create repository with `IDocumentStore` instance. Is this valid approch?

Is there another approch where I would create `IDocumentStore` instance and use that instance in application lifetime?